# Image not downloading with filter applied in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, image-processing, download

My const "handleDownload" is not applying filters when downloading the image:

```
  const handleDownload = () => {
    const node = document.getElementById("preview-image");
    const filterStyle = {
      filter: "sepia(50%) contrast(130%) brightness(85%) saturate(110%)",
    };
    html2canvas(node, {
      style: Object.assign({}, html2canvas.defaultCss, filterStyle),
    }).then((canvas) => {
      canvas.toBlob((blob) => {
        const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        const link = document.createElement("a");
        link.download = "minha-polaroid.png";
        link.href = url;
        link.click();
        URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
      });
    });
  };
```

My preview of the image on the website:

```
                <div
                  id="preview-image"
                  className={`relative ${
                    bannerType === "mini"
                      ? "w-[204.09px] h-[325.03px] border border-black border-opacity-25 rounded-[2px] p-[16px] pt-5 pb-12"
                      : bannerType === "square"
                      ? "w-[272.12px] h-[325.03px] border border-black border-opacity-25 rounded-[2px] p-[16px] pt-5 pb-12"
                      : bannerType === "wide"
                      ? "w-[408.18px] h-[325.03px] border border-black border-opacity-25 rounded-[2px] p-[16px] pt-5 pb-12"
                      : "w-[272.12px] h-[325.03px]"
                  } bg-white relative`}
                >
                  <img
                    src={image.preview || "/assets/placeholder-image.png"}
                    alt="imagem enviada"
                    className={`w-full h-full object-cover rounded-[4px] ${
                      !bannerType ? "" : bannerType === "mini"
                      ? "filter-sepia filter-contrast filter-brightness filter-saturate"
                      : bannerType === "square"
                      ? "filter-sepia filter-contrast filter-brightness filter-saturate"
                      : bannerType === "wide"
                      ? "filter-sepia filter-contrast filter-brightness filter-saturate"
                      : ""
                    }`}
                    style={{ filter: 'sepia(50%) contrast(130%) brightness(85%) saturate(110%)' }}
                  />
                </div>
```

My download button:

```
     <div className="flex justify-center items-center">
         <button
             onClick={handleDownload}
             className="bg-white border mt-2 border-gray-300 w-44 rounded-md py-1 px-4 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-50 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500">
             Baixar Polaroid
         </button>
     </div>
```

I have tried several alternatives but none have worked, I want the filter to come out on the downloaded image but so far I haven't had the result.

Comment: Does it display with the filter if you would display the canvas instead of downloading?

Comment: Yes, on the screen it appears with the filter, but when it comes time to download the filter does not appear.